# Adding text before and after selected text - VBA user form

Tags: vba, ms-word, richtextbox, userform

I'm using a VBA user-form in order to edit some text by using a rich text format textbox from the InkEdit control.
I'm trying to insert html tags in specific location when the user click on a command button on the user-form.

for example if the user clicks the "strong" button the following code is executed and the text is inserted on the cursor location inside the textbox:

```
InkEdit1.SelText = "<strong>"
```

I have another button for the closing statment which runs:

```
InkEdit1.SelText = "</strong>"
```

I'm trying to find a way that the opening statement ans the closing statement will be applied together. When the user will select a text from the text box and click the button then "strong" will be inserted before the selection and "/strong" will be inserted after the selection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
InkEdit1.SelText = "<strong>" & InkEdit1.SelText & "</strong>"
```

If you really want to get fancy, you can reselect just the original text:

```
Dim lPos As Long
lPos = InkEdit1.SelStart

Dim lLength As Long
lLength = InkEdit1.SelLength

InkEdit1.SelText = "<strong>" & InkEdit1.SelText & "</strong>"

InkEdit1.SelStart = lPos + Len("<strong>")
InkEdit1.SelLength = lLength
```

Protip: Make sure the "HideSelection" property is set to "False"

[image]

If you're not using an actual RitchTextBox, try this: Toos > Additional Controls > check Microsoft Rich Textbox

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It works but the text in the middle changes as well. It's a rich text format textbox so I want to keep the original formatting of text.

Comment: There is no "HideSelection" property to this textbox.

Comment: I was under the impression you were using a Rich Textbox. Post updated to include screenshot of property and how to include Rich Textbox. The property doesn't affect the code, though--it just keeps the selection visible when the user clicks the button (thus loosing focus on the RTF). Does the code work for you, though?

Comment: No it's works the same as the first one. If I have colored text inside the selection then after I run it all colors turns black